# Error al iniciar servidor con Nodemon

Tags: nodejs, linux, ubuntu, npm

Tengo en mi Ubuntu 20.04 un proyecto con node, mientras lo desarrollo, uso Nodemon.
Hoy cuando he entrado en el proyecto y he hecho `npm run dev` (que es el script que tengo configurado), me sale esto :

```
> nodemon ./src/index.js
sh: 1: nodemon: Permission denied
```

He mirado y el index.js está bien, y todas las rutas también

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo o porque ocurre?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba intentando instalar nodemon con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: ¡Hola, finalmente si me sirvió, muchas gracias!